# Can you chain external monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have two external monitors that I'd like to hookup to my laptop. Both monitors have VGA and DVI-D ports and one monitor has a bunch of other ports too (Display port, usb, S-Video, Composite). Neither of them have an HDMI input port. The computer I want to hookup to the two external monitors has only one HDMI port, and no other display ports (It has 3 USB ports but currently they're in use.)

Is there a way to run an HDMI cable to one monitor, and then run a cable from the first monitor to the 2nd monitor and display information on all three? Or do I have to split the HDMI output from the computer?

Comment: DisplayPort 1.2 is chainable, HDMI/DVI (or HDMI/DVI over a DisplayPort physical plug/socket as can happen) is not.  http://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/

Comment: Ahh so the monitors would need a DisplayPort output on them to make it work. Thanks!!!

Comment: And your PC would also need a DisplayPort output as well for this method to work.

Answer (score 4):

All of those ports on the monitor are  are simply inputs, they cannot output signal. They are also usually switched so only one is active at a time anyway. There would be no way to chain monitors together in the fashion you describe.

If you split the HDMI cable output (and to be honest I'm not sure there are splitters for it, but would not be surprised, as there are for VGA/DVI), then it would be the exact same signal to both monitors - you wouldn't have an extended desktop option.

They do make USB to VGA/DVI/HDMI adapters so you can use your USB ports for monitors if you get one of those, though as you mention they are all in use, so you may want to purchase a powered USB hub as well.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I would have liked to have had the functionality of three displays instead of just two!